# media queries are being ignored

Tags: html, css, media-queries, media

I set the media query for desktop, tablet and mobile. desktop seems to be working fine, but the tablet and mobile are being ignored.
Here is my page: http://moran88.github.io/coursera-moran/mod2_solution/

Please help I don't understand the reason of this happening.

Thanks

Comment: You should paste your code so is easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your css is missing some brackets, try this:

```
h1 {
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
    text-align:center;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
}

.row {
    width:100%;
}


.text {
    background-color:  #b3ccff;
    height:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;

}
p {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.title {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left:8px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-color:black;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;


}




#chicken {
    background-color:  #2d8659;
    color:white;
}

#beef {
    background-color:  #d1d1e0;

}

#sushi {
    background-color:  #80ffd4;
}




@media (min-width: 992px){
    .col-lg-3{
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
        padding: 15px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
    .col-md-6 {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;

    }

    .col-md-12 {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

}
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .col-sm-12 {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }


}
```